# Why won't Grid rows with height Auto resize with scale-transformed content?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Given the following code, I would have expected the red and green boxes to end up next to eachother, but as you can see in the screenshot of the result, they do not. Instead, the grid rows are sized to accommodate their full size, even though there is a render transform that scales them to half their height.

*Is there a way to make the grid rows actually resize themselves and adjust to their contents?*

I want this because I couldn't animate the heights of the rows, so I want to animate the heights of their contents instead.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Height="300"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Background="Red">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="200"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Background="Green">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY=".5" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: red vs green]

Comment: If you're just using the objects to do your sizing just swap a Grid for a StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

As Sheridan says, a RenderTransform is just moving stuff around - independent of other elements. The neat thing is that it's fully hardware accelerated.

To have the system perform animations AND affect layout is a bit more tricky. You probably want to aim for not doing a pure resize, but instead use render transforms to have one element move on top of another, hence hiding it.

But, if you really do want a true resize of content, here's a way to do it.

First, I've added a row with height * at the bottom to allow your Auto rows to just use the size they need.
Secondly, I've created an animation (using Blend of course :) ) - and named the key frames in it, to be able to access them from code behind.

Lastly I modify the animation in the .cs file, and run the animation - voila! Note, this will not be hardware accelerated, but should work for simple UIs.

Code can also be found at: https://github.com/andyhammar/Wp81ResizeRowsTestApp

**.xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="AnimateRed">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="_redBorder">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" x:Name="redAnimationFromKeyFrame" Value="300"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" x:Name="redAnimationToKeyFrame" Value="200">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border 
        x:Name="_redBorder" 
        Height="300"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Background="Red">
    </Border>
    <Border 
        x:Name="_greenBorder" 
        Height="200"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Background="Green">
    </Border>

    <StackPanel 
        Grid.Row="2"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button 
            x:Name="redSmallButton"
            Content="red small"
            Click="RedSmallButton_OnClick"/>
        <Button 
            x:Name="redLargeButton"
            Content="red large"
            Click="RedLargeButton_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
    private void RedSmallButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        redAnimationFromKeyFrame.Value = 300;
        redAnimationToKeyFrame.Value = 200;
        AnimateRed.Begin();
    }

    private void RedLargeButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        redAnimationFromKeyFrame.Value = 200;
        redAnimationToKeyFrame.Value = 300;
        AnimateRed.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

They do, but I'd suggest that you use the [`LayoutTransform` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) instead. The difference is that `LayoutTransform` is performed *before* the `Arrange` and `Measure` methods are called, so the new size is taken into consideration and `RenderTransform` is performed afterwards, so it ignores any dimension changes.

You can find a full explanation of the differences in the [LayoutTransform vs. RenderTransform - What's the Difference?](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/19/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference.html) page on the Scott Logic website.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Height="300"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Background="Red">
        <Border.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5" />
        </Border.LayoutTransform>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="200"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Background="Green">
        <Border.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY=".5" />
        </Border.LayoutTransform>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that tag... all the same, you can still use it. See the answer to the [LayoutTransform not in Windows Phone Toolkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663740/layouttransform-not-in-windows-phone-toolkit) question.

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't get it to animate properly; I can't figure out how to specify the target properties in the storyboards to get at the scales in the custom transformer.